# The Relation Between Kronecker's Delta and the Permutation Symbol

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, permutations, tensors, kronecker-symbol

The **Kronecker's Delta** is defined as

$$\delta_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
1 & i=j \\
0 & i \ne j
\end{cases}$$

Also, the **Permuation Symbol** known as **Levi Cevita**'s Symbol is introduced as

$$\varepsilon_{ijk}=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{$ijk$ is an even permutation of $123$} \\
-1 & \text{$ijk$ is an odd permutation of $123$} \\
0 & \text{$ijk$ has two same indices}
\end{cases}$$

where $i$, $j$, and $k$ are natural numbers $1,2,3$. These symbols are widely used in vector and tensor analysis and in differential geometry. There is a relation between them as the following theorem states.

> **Theorem.** The following relation holds between the Kronecker's Delta and permutation symbol
>   $$\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{pqr}=
> \begin{vmatrix}
> \delta_{ip} & \delta_{iq} & \delta_{ir} \\
> \delta_{jp} & \delta_{jq} & \delta_{jr} \\
> \delta_{kp} & \delta_{kq} & \delta_{kr} \\
> \end {vmatrix}$$
>   where $|\cdot|$ denotes the determinant.

I am looking for different proofs of this theorem.  Also, I don't want to prove it by just investigating that the equality holds for different choices of the indices one by one!

I don't have any idea to take a first step. Any hint or help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 6):

For each $i \in \left\{1,2,3\right\}$, let $e_i$ be the column vector in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ whose $i$-th entry is $1$ and whose other two entries are $0$. (In other words, $e_i$ is the $i$-th column of the $3\times 3$ identity matrix.)

For any $i, j, k \in \left\{1,2,3\right\}$, let $K_{ijk}$ be the $3\times 3$-matrix whose columns are $e_i, e_j, e_k$ (in this order).

Observe the following:

1. For any $i, j, k \in \left\{1,2,3\right\}$, we have $\det K_{ijk} = \varepsilon_{ijk}$.
2. For any $u, v \in \left\{1,2,3\right\}$, we have $\delta_{uv} = e_u^T e_v$. Thus, for any $i, j, k, p, q, r \in \left\{1,2,3\right\}$, we have

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
\delta_{ip} & \delta_{iq} & \delta_{ir} \\
\delta_{jp} & \delta_{jq} & \delta_{jr} \\
\delta_{kp} & \delta_{kq} & \delta_{kr} \\
\end{matrix}\right)
= K_{ijk}^T K_{pqr} ,$$
so that
$$\det\left(\begin{matrix}
\delta_{ip} & \delta_{iq} & \delta_{ir} \\
\delta_{jp} & \delta_{jq} & \delta_{jr} \\
\delta_{kp} & \delta_{kq} & \delta_{kr} \\
\end{matrix}\right)
= \det\left(K_{ijk}^T K_{pqr}\right) = \det K_{ijk} \det K_{pqr} = \varepsilon_{ijk} \varepsilon_{pqr}
$$